# Which of CcAvenue PHP kit 4 files will go in controller and View, in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, ccavenue

I am trying to integrate  CcAvenue PHP kit 4 files  in controller and View, Which file will go in controller and View, I know dataFrom  will go In view

Comment: Which of CcAvenue  PHP kit 4 files  will go in controller and View, ccavRequestHandler.php ,ccavResponseHandler.php, Crypto.php, dataFrom file will go IN controller and View, I know dataFrom  will go In view

Comment: Will All Files go In View folder and just there will be file to load view from controller from the action of form of dataFrom.php File.

Comment: Found the Solution, II added all files to View and Just through a controller to send request from form to view.

But currently getting Error as Error Code: 10002     Merchant Authentication failed